# Adding activity to queryIntentActivities list

Tags: android, android-intent, installed-applications

I have my android app which gets all installed applications via - `queryIntentActivities`
.

and I need to be able to add my own activity to this list, so I can start it, when this activity is picked, How can I do it?

Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an `<intent-filter>` on your `<activity>` which matches the `Intent` that you are creating. Something akin to:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="???"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

(where `???` would be replaced by whatever `APP_DEFALUT_MIME_TYPE` is, I guess)

Comment: Thanks, that helped :) And by the way is there any way to pass an uri to this activity through intent?

Comment: @unresolved_external: Neither `ACTION_SEND` nor `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` use the data `Uri` in an `Intent`.

Comment: So basically, what I need to do is to put uri to my Intent and then parse it will appear in the Bundle of activity which was launched via this Intent?

Comment: @unresolved_external: I am sorry, but I do not understand your last comment. I repeat: neither `ACTION_SEND` nor `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` use the data `Uri` in an `Intent`.

Comment: @unresolved_external: I have no idea what you are referring to, sorry.

Comment: Ok, in android we can set intent type via setData method by passing Uri to it, so if I set it like this, would I be able to get this uri, in activity which was started?

Comment: @unresolved_external: If you are using `EXTRA_STREAM` with `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, you put the `Uri` (converted to a string) of the data to be streamed as the value of `EXTRA_STREAM`. Otherwise, there is no `Uri`, and any attempt to use `setData()` is likely to prevent your `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` from working in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I already figured it out by myself, Thank you for you time. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I needed to clean/rebuild my project before my internal Activity showed up in my `queryIntentActivities` list, so if you're doing the above and it still isn't working, a clean might be worth a try.